# Unable to download Java dependencies with Dockerfile

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, dockerfile

Well, there is this java project using maven, and the `pom.xml` file is like [THIS](https://gist.github.com/joaocasarin/ea2ada99d9a1209ac1af06a2cd757214)

When I run locally `./mvnw -B dependency:go-offline` and `./mvnw -o package -DskipTests`, it works fine. However when I use it in Dockerfile, it just fails on some dependencies...

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:18.0.2.1_1-jdk-focal AS builder
ENV APP=/home/meapi/app
WORKDIR $APP
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw -B dependency:go-offline
COPY src src
RUN ./mvnw -o package -DskipTests

FROM eclipse-temurin:18.0.2.1_1-jre-focal as dev
RUN addgroup --system meapi && adduser --system --group meapi
ENV spring_profiles_active=development
ENV APP=/home/meapi/app
WORKDIR $APP
RUN chown -R meapi:meapi $APP
USER meapi
COPY --chown=meapi:meapi --from=builder $APP/target/*.jar $APP/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/usr/meapi/app/app.jar" ]
```

This is the error:

```bash
=> ERROR [builder 7/7] RUN ./mvnw -o package -DskipTests                                                                            12.9s
------                                                                                                                                     
 > [builder 7/7] RUN ./mvnw -o package -DskipTests:                                                                                        
#14 7.221 [INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                                                                  
#14 8.659 [INFO]                                                                                                                           
#14 8.659 [INFO] ---------------------< com.me:me-api >----------------------                                                  
#14 8.660 [INFO] Building me-api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                                                                   
#14 8.660 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
#14 10.43 [WARNING] The POM for javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1 is missing, no dependency information available
#14 11.03 [WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.13.3 is missing, no dependency information available
#14 11.11 [WARNING] The POM for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8 is missing, no dependency information available
#14 11.19 [WARNING] The POM for net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.10 is missing, no dependency information available
#14 11.20 [WARNING] The POM for net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.10 is missing, no dependency information available
#14 11.35 [WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6 is missing, no dependency information available
#14 12.79 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#14 12.79 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
#14 12.79 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#14 12.82 [INFO] Total time:  5.758 s
#14 12.83 [INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-13T19:58:59Z
#14 12.83 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#14 12.85 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project me-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.me:me-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.13.3, net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8, net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.10, net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.10, org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
#14 12.85 [ERROR] 
#14 12.85 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
#14 12.85 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
#14 12.85 [ERROR] 
#14 12.85 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
#14 12.85 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./mvnw -o package -DskipTests]: exit code: 1
```

The command I use to run it is `docker build --no-cache --platform linux/amd64 --tag api --target dev .`. How am I supposed to proceed and successfully build the image?

Comment: maven's go-offline is known to be buggy, I would suggest using [Go Offline Maven Plugin](https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin) instead.

Comment: Hey @AndreyB.Panfilov thanks for your answer. Would you mind to tell me whether I should add all those dynapicDependencies set in the plugin.configuration of that plugin? I am not soooo familiar with java and I am not sure about it.

Comment: that depends on your project, at first step I would recommend to replace yours `./mvnw -B dependency:go-offline` by `./mvnw -B de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:1.2.8:resolve-dependencies` and check whether project builds successfully in offline mode or not, if not, you will need to configure plugin.

Comment: at first would you recommend just copying what the plugin from the github readme or should I change something like leaving the configuration clean?

Comment: just replace command on Dockerfile

Comment: I got a similar error, just a different package: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) on project me-api: Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 has not been downloaded from it before. `

Comment: looks like you are doing something wrong. [that](https://gist.github.com/andreybpanfilov/a22cf9a200d1960dccadf0398ea7ea3d) is how it works in my env - it fails because there is no sources.